# Ember-simple-auth custom authorizer not called

Tags: ember.js, ember-simple-auth

I'm trying to implement custom auth with ember-simple-auth and I stuck at the start. I have app/autheticators/digest.js

```
import Base from 'ember-simple-auth/authenticators/base';
import Ember from 'ember';

export default Base.extend({
  restore(data) {
    //
  },
  authenticate(email, password) {
    console.log(email, password);
    return new Ember.RSVP.Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
      Ember.run(function() {
          resolve({email: email, password: password});
        });
    });
  },
  invalidate(data) {
    //
  }
});
```

app/authorizers/digest.js

```
import Base from 'simple-auth/authorizers/base';  
import Ember from 'ember';

export default Base.extend({  
  header: function() {
    return "test-digest";
  },

  authorize: function(sessionData, block) {
    console.log('authorize...');
    block('Authorization', this.get('header'));
  }
});
```

Login component:

```
import Ember from 'ember';
import CryptoJS from 'npm:crypto-js';

export default Ember.Component.extend({
    session: Ember.inject.service('session'),
    actions: {
        login() {
            let { email, password } = this.getProperties('email', 'password');
            this.get("session").authenticate('autheticator:digest', 
                email, CryptoJS.SHA256(password).toString()).catch((reason) => {
                this.set('errorMessage', reason.error);
            });
        }
    }

});
```

Authentication called properly (I hope), but "authorize" in authorizer never called. I also tried add some values to ENV:

```
  ENV['simple-auth'] = {
    authorizer: 'authorizer:digest',
    crossOriginWhitelist: ['http://prod-drunkedguru.rhcloud.com:80/'] // ['*'] I also tried
  };
```

But nothing changed. What I'm doing wrong?

P.S. I'm using EmberJS 1.13.0 with EAS 1.0.

Comment: Hi, Crabar. I have same problem. Can you tell me how to fix this problem?I check marcoow's answer. But I very confused how to set session to $.ajax. If you have the example, can you show me? Thanks a lot.

Comment: Sure. It looks next: this.get('session').authorize('authorizer:digest', (headerName, headerValue) => {
            const headers = {};
            headers[headerName] = headerValue;
            Ember.$.ajax({
                url: "url",
                method: "GET",
                data: {
                    })
                },
                headers: headers
            }).then(function(result) {
                //
                });
            });

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you're using ESA 1.0. In that version the authorizer isn't automatically called anymore but you need to call it manually. There is the `DataAdapterMixin` that you can use to automatically authorizer Ember Data requests though. See this blog post for guidance on migrating to 1.0: http://log.simplabs.com/post/131698328145/updating-to-ember-simple-auth-10

Comment: Thx for answer. Will it work for Ember.$.ajax requests?

Comment: Sure you can authorize all sorts of requests - check the docs: http://ember-simple-auth.com/api/classes/SessionService.html#method_authorize

Comment: If you're using `Ember.$.ajax` you need to do that manually yes - in an actual app you should have an `Ember.Service` of course that wraps `Ember.$.ajax` and implements authorization as well.

Comment: Thanks for help. I will try it soon.

Comment: Yeah! It's really work. So hard to find not outdated example of using ESA  =(.

Comment: @marcoow can you give an example of the service that wraps Ember.$.ajax and implements authorization as well?